# Missing font resource dictionary after stamping text in iText 7

Tags: itext7

I have an existing PDF that doesn't contain any fonts (image only).  I want to stamp some additional text onto the first page using low level canvas operations.  When I do this in iText 7, the resulting PDF is missing the Fonts resource dictionary entry (which results in an NPE when parsing the resulting file).

Do I have to do something besides canvas.setFontAndSize() to get the font resource to get added to the output?

Here's a unit test that recreates the issue:

```
public class CheckFontResourceInclusion {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        // create a document to stamp
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try(PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos))){
            doc.addNewPage();
        }

        // stamp it
        StampingProperties stampProps = new StampingProperties();

        PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont();

        ByteArrayOutputStream resultStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try(PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())), new PdfWriter(resultStream), stampProps)){
            PdfPage page = doc.getPage(1);
            PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), new PdfResources(), doc);
            canvas.beginText();
            canvas.setTextRenderingMode(2);
            canvas.setFontAndSize(font, 42);
            canvas.setTextMatrix(1, 0, 0, -1, 100, 100);
            canvas.showText("TEXT TO STAMP");
            canvas.endText();
        }


        // parse text
        try(PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(resultStream.toByteArray())))){
            LocationTextExtractionStrategy strat = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
            PdfCanvasProcessor processor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(strat);
            processor.processPageContent(doc.getPage(1));
            Assert.assertEquals("TEXT TO STAMP", strat.getResultantText());
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the resulting failure:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor$SetTextFontOperator.invoke(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:811)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.invokeOperator(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:456)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.processContent(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:285)
    at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.canvas.parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.processPageContent(PdfCanvasProcessor.java:306)
    at
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is the same as in this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53230326/1729265): You use a throw-away resources object, so the font resource is missing in the result.

You can fix this by using the actual page resources. Simply replace

```java
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), new PdfResources(), doc);
```

by

```java
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(), page.getResources(), doc);
```